# Compilation error with LuaLaTeX (luaotfload- database.lua)

Tags: fonts, errors, luatex, luaotfload

This file does not compile after updating TeXLive 2013 :

```
 \RequirePackage{ifluatex}
 \documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
 \ifluatex 
 \usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
 \usepackage[urw-garamond,uppercase=upright,greeklowercase=upright]{mathdesign}
 \usepackage{garamondx}
 \usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
 \else
 \usepackage[urw-garamond,uppercase=upright,greeklowercase=upright]{mathdesign}
 \usepackage{garamondx}
 \usepackage{pstricks-add}
 \usepackage{mathrsfs}
\fi

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=1cm,algebraic=true,arrowscale=1.2}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-3)(5,3)
\psaxes[linewidth=1pt,Dx=1,Dy=1,labels=none,ticksize=-0pt 0pt]{->}(0,0)(-2,-3)(5,3)
\psdots[dotstyle=*](-1,0)
\psdots[dotstyle=*](3,0)

\begin{psclip}
{\psframe[linestyle=none](-2,-3)(5,3)}
{\psplot[linewidth=1pt,plotpoints=2000]{-2}{4}{(1/2)*(x+1)*(x-3)}}%
\end{psclip}
\uput[dl](-1,0){$x_1$}
\uput[dr](3,0){$x_2$}
\uput[d](4.8,0){$x$}
\uput[l](0,2.8){$y$}
\uput[dl](0,0){$0$}
\uput[ur](-1.8,2){$\mathscr{P}$} 
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}

 ! LuaTeX error ...texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-   database.lua:2121:
  attempt to call upvalue 'utf8length' (a nil value).
 <to be read again> 
 relax 
 l.100 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont
```

Comment: Did you make an update today or yesterday? An update yesterday broke my luaotfload. If that's the case, you could try to roll back a backup. If you use texlive, you can use the `restore` command of the tlmgr.

Comment: I have submitted a bug report https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/164 Restoring the previous version solves the issue (temporarily).

Comment: @egreg Delete the font cache and call luaotfload -u on the command line to rebuild it manually. Then it should work again. See also here https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/156

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry, but this is by no means an acceptable way of doing things. Users should not be required to do mysterious and undocumented maneuvers. *What* cache should I remove? Getting an unusable system after an update is not nice, is it? Your situation was different, as you seemed to be testing a beta version.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How can I delete the fontcache? calling luaotfload-tool --update --force didn't work.

Comment: @egreg: Run luaotfload-tool --help and you will get the pathes of the font caches. Delete the files there manually. You could also try luaotfload-tool --cache=purge oder --cache=erase.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Which is precisely what I *don't* want to do. The tool should do it or, if impossible, a warning from the package should appear. Not an unscrutable error message.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I deleted the font cache and called luaotfload-tool -u and get the meta nil value message.

Comment: @egreg: Sure in a perfect world this wouldn't be necessary, but sometimes things breaks and the people have to delete the biber cache or as in this case the luatex cache.

Comment: Ah I have to remove the font database too... It seems to work now.

Comment: @JuriRobl: Yes I meant all the font cache related files. Imho the important files to delete are the files in \texlive\2013\texmf-var\luatex-cache\generic\names, but it is probably a good idea to remove font related files too. Also I just tested the update: After removing the files in \names and running luaotfload-tool --update everything worked fine again.

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer `fab@debian:~$ cd texlive/2013/
fab@debian:~/texlive/2013$ luaotfload-tool --update 
luaotfload | db : Font names database not found, generating new one.
luaotfload | db : This can take several minutes; please be patient`.It seems to work now.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Now it can't find some fonts anymore: `>luaotfload-tool --find="Minion Pro Italic" --fuzzy
luaotfload | resolve : Cannot find "Minion Pro Italic" in index.
luaotfload | resolve : Hint: use the --fuzzy option to display suggestions.
luaotfload | resolve : Looking for close matches, this may take a while ...
luaotfload | query : Distance from "minionproitalic": 2
    Minion Pro Italic
    Minion Pro Italic`

Comment: @JuriRobl: Hm. On my system Minion Pro is in a resource folder of the adobe reader and if I remember correctly luaotfload on texlive was never able to find it there. But in miktex it worked but with luaotfload 2.4 in only works if I use the file name, so something has changed. I made a bug report.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have it normally installed. The strange thing is, the fuzzy search finds the exact same (correct) font, but it claims there is a difference between the result and my search.

Comment: @JuriRobl The italics of Minion Pro seem to deviate from the rest of the font with respect to naming convention. The next bugfix release of Luaotfload will come with a fix. Btw. if you want to look up a font name the way *fontspec* does it, you are going to have to use Xetex modifier syntax. E.g. ``luaotfload-tool --find="name:Minion Pro/I"``. This should work regardless of the insufficient full name lookup.

Answer (score 1):

You mention you use TeXLive. Until a bugfix to the `luaotfload` package is pushed to the CTAN, you may want to issue the command

```
sudo tlmgr restore luaotfload 31286
```

to revert to the previous version, numbered 2.3a, of this package. (The recent buggy version, numbered 2.4, has CTAN/TeXLive number 32538.)

Comment: A new version of `luaotfload` has been pushed a few minutes ago.