# compilation error with luaotfload-fontloader since update Mactex/Texlive2013

Tags: luaotfload

I'm using MacOs X Maverick with the latest MacTeX 2013 (updated 22/05/2014).

I'm getting this error error message :

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local/tex/gregoriotex/gregoriotex-signs.tex)  
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local/tex/gregoriotex/gregoriotex-syllable.tex)  
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local/tex/gregoriotex/gregoriotex-symbols.tex  

! LuaTeX error ...xmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-fontloader.lua:4570:  
attempt to index local 'whatfeatures' (a nil value).  
<to be read again>   
\par   
l.116   

?
```

I'v searched on this site and found this topic : [Compilation error with LuaLaTeX (luaotfload- database.lua)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152238/compilation-error-with-lualatex-luaotfload-database-lua)

I've tried every solutions given in that topic :

- delete font cache and run luaotfload-tool -vvv -u ==> successful, but I still get the error with lualatex
- downgrade luaotfload package and rerun luaotfload-tool -vvv -u ==> successful, but I still get the error with lualatex

I've checked that my luaotfload-database.lua is the patched one since this issue is well-known.

I still have the problem :

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local/tex/gregoriotex/gregoriotex-signs.tex)  
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local/tex/gregoriotex/gregoriotex-syllable.tex)  
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local/tex/gregoriotex/gregoriotex-symbols.tex  

! LuaTeX error ...xmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-fontloader.lua:4570:  
attempt to index local 'whatfeatures' (a nil value).  
<to be read again>   
\par   
l.116   

?
```

If you need more informations to help me, do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: I'm just asking lualatex to work ! There are questions with less research but the got answers, like the one i referred to. So i don't understand why you are saying my question is not clear.

Comment: Your edits make it a lot clearer what problems you're trying to solve. It would be even more helpful if you posted an MWE that gives rise to the problem and if you provided further, background-type information -- e.g., --which OS, which version of luaotfload -- about your setup.

Comment: I've added OS. What is MWE ?

Comment: MWE: Minimum working example, an acronym mentioned rather frequently on this site. Basically, a (possibly non-working) LaTeX document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` that generates the problem, or problems, that you're looking to fix. Without this information, we basically can't tell what actually gives rise to the error messages you report getting, making it rather difficult to provide a diagnosis, let alone prescribe a cure.

Comment: I've identify the source of the problem : package gregoriotex.

I've made a simple tex file without this package, compilation is ok.  
I've putted the `\usepackage{gregoriotex}` and I got the error.  

Now my question is :
the error message happens just after `(/usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local/tex/gregoriotex/gregoriotex-symbols.tex`  

Is it normal that this package is installed in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` and not in `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-local` ?

Comment: I've identify the source of the problem : package gregoriotex.
I've made a simple tex file without this package, compilation is ok.  
I've putted the `\usepackage{gregoriotex}` and I got the error.  
The error message happens just after `(/usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local/tex/gregoriotex/gregoriotex-symbols.tex`  
Is it normal that this package is installed in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` and not in `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-local` ?
I think that luaotfload-tool do not find the gregoriotex fonts as there are not in the /usr/local/texlive/2013 directory. Could I be right ?

Comment: The directory `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` would seem to be the correct place for packages that aren't directly part of the TeXLive distribution for whatever reason. If this package lived under `/usr/local/texlive/2013` one would have to reinstall it manually every time a new TeXLive version is distributed (usually once a year).

Comment: I've found the solution : recompile the gregoriotex binaries and fonts.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem solved with a software update